# ABAP Stdout and Stderr

Tags: stdout, abap, stderr

Does ABAP allow writing to stdout and stderr?  I need to write small programs to test interface connections to SAP systems via a job scheduler(Cronacle).  For instance, start/write 'Hello World!' + date + time to stdout/exit.  I'm a .net programmer tasked with this seemingly TRIVIAL program and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Appliaction Log (Transaction SLG0, SLG1) Tables BAL*, is very very cool for tracing... it is much fun, because it is good even for background tasks, different user accounts, invisible for the user, and the erasure of old trace entries can be definied whilst creating them. it´s heaven for me not having to debug any more.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your running SAP on a UNIX / Linux based system with an ABAP stack. SAP tries to abstract away as much of the underlying OS as possiable. This technique would hold on Windows with some minor modifications.

To interact with the OS have a look in SM49 "External OS Commands" from here you can set up a command to run cat and pass in the values you want written out to the console.

I would think you would be better off writing your messages to a file on the host system through. To do that;

```
OPEN DATASET i_file FOR OUTPUT IN TEXT MODE ENCODING DEFAULT.
```

then write data into the file using;

```
TRANSFER wa_text TO i_file.
```

then when your done don't forget

```
CLOSE DATASET i_file.
```

You can then look at the contents of the file in AL11 or pick it up directly off the host. If you want to see the messages as they are being printed on the unix host. Connect in with a console and use less +F /var/log/ or tail. On windows I am sure there is an equal substitute.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to write "debugging information" like what you are asking about. Two possibilities mentioned here in previous answers are the application log (SLG1 and SBAL* function modules) and writing to a file.

For your situation, however, you mention running programs in the background. In that case, your best bet is to simply issue messages with MESSAGE (you can restrict issuing of messages to background processing by checking the value of SY-BATCH).

Messages issued by a program running in the background are visible in the job log when you go to SM37.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Application Logging - http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/d3/1fa03940fab918e10000000a114084/frameset.htm